# File error: Cannot open load file

Tags: package

I have the following ~/.emacs:

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(require 'highlight-symbol)
(global-set-key [(control f3)] 'highlight-symbol)
(global-set-key [f3] 'highlight-symbol-next)
(global-set-key [(shift f3)] 'highlight-symbol-prev)
(global-set-key [(meta f3)] 'highlight-symbol-query-replace)
```

Then I added the file highlight-symbol.el to my ~/.emacs.d folder.

However when I start emacs I get:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘~/.emacs’:

File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, highlight-symbol
```

I am new to emacs, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the help from `require` (`C-h f require`)

> (require FEATURE &optional FILENAME NOERROR)
>
> If feature FEATURE is not loaded, load it from FILENAME.
>   If FEATURE is not a member of the list 'features', then the feature
>   is not loaded; so load the file FILENAME.
>   If FILENAME is omitted, the printname of FEATURE is used as the file name,
>   and 'load' will try to load this name appended with the suffix '.elc' or
>   '.el', in that order.

So let's look at `load` help (either `C-h f load` or simply use `TAB` to navigate to the blue link then use`RET`):

> This function searches the directories in `load-path'.

Again we can have a look at `load-path` help (either `C-h v load-path`, since it's a variable, or navigating to the link) and, probably, find that `.emacs.d` is not in the list.

This can be fixed by adding this to the init file:

> (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")

For it to take effect immediately you can use `C-x C-e` (`eval-last-sexp`) with point at end of line.

Comment: Can I just say that your step by step was far more important than the answer? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the time this question was asked, but today (Emacs 26.3) I've run into the same error. My config was basically like so:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (expand-region))))

(require 'expand-region)
```

The reason it didn't work was because by the time `require` was executed, `~/.emacs.d/elpa/expand-region-XXXXXXXX.XXXX` was not in `load-path`. I fixed by putting `require` inside `after-init-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (progn
  (require 'expand-region)
  )))
```